# var handler = MyEvent in VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a question about [his article](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2010/05/27/WhyYouShouldUseEventHandlerGetInvocationList.aspx).

I converted the source code to Vb.net, but I have a problem with this line :

```
 var handler = MyEvent
```

Can anyone help me translating this line to VB.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var handler = MyEvent;
if (handler == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("No listeners");
    return;
}
```

can be translated to

```
Dim handler = MyEventEvent
If handler Is Nothing
     Console.WriteLine("No listeners")
     Return
End If
```

---

[image]

Comment: Then i get the error: <name> 'Is an event and can not be called directly.

Comment: Are you sure? If the event is named *MyEvent*, get the delegate by *MyEventEvent*

Comment: Ahh Yes thank you so much. My development environment has spun (:

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to declare a custom event with the Custom keyword to access the underlying delegate.  It is well explained in this [MSDN Library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt1k2w4e.aspx).

It should be noted that catching exceptions like this is **very** unwise.  Catching an exception requires that you restore the program state as though the event was never raised.  Undoing any changes made the partially executed code.  That's impossible with events, implicit with the contract for events is that you don't know anything about the code that subscribed a handler for the event.  Which implies that it entirely impossible to restore state.  The catch block *must* appear in the event handler, not in the code that raises the event.  Ignore the advise this blogger is trying to give you.

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be either

```
Dim handler As EventHandler = MyEvent
```

or

```
Dim handler As EventHandler = AddressOf MyEvent
```

Comment: I have try those two but MyEvent is not a method and AddressOf must get an method. The first one doesn't work because he think i will call the Event :/