# Assign EventHandler to a local variable before invoking

Tags: c#

I noticed that quite a lot of code is using following code snippet to invoke event handler.

```
Public event EventHandler Handler;

Protected void OnEvent(){
      var handler = this.Handler;
      If(null!=handler){
          handler(this, new EventArgs());
      }
}
```

Why does it assign `Handler` to a local variable before invoking other than invoking the event on `Handler` directly. Is there any difference between those?

Comment: Would [this previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279901/var-handler-myevent-in-vb-net) also apply to your question?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this Eric Lipert's article on MSDN https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/29/events-and-races/

Comment: Try this thread. Google is invaluable for these things. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147397/why-assign-a-handler-to-an-event-before-calling-it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786383/c-sharp-events-and-thread-safety this is better reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical way to avoid a race condition.

When you're on a pre-emptively multi-tasked system, or worse, a multi-core system, a lot can happen between the `if (Handler != null)` check and the actual `Handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);`. Most importantly, it's perfectly possible that `Handler` wasn't `null` during the check, but is during the invocation itself - and now you've got a really hard to track `NullReferenceException`.

In contrast, by storing the `Handler` to a local variable, you ensure no other thread is going to mess with it while you are doing your check and invoke.

Note that this still leaves you open to *other* kinds of race conditions :)